# TypeError got multiple values for keyword argument queue

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot

I am stuck at this error that I am not managing to fix. I have found relevant cases, but I am having a hard time applying it to my own problem.
Can someone help me understand why this Typerror happens and / or help me find a solution? (please respnd to me as a beginner)

I am using python in a raspberry pi and pika 1.1.0.

this is my traceback:

```
  File "amqp.py", line 33, in <module>
    no_ack=True)
TypeError: basic_consume() got multiple values for keyword argument 'queue
```

this what I think is the relevant code:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):

    printer.inverseOn()
    printer.println(' ' + '{:<31}'.format("TXT MESSAGE"))
    printer.inverseOff()

    printer.println(body)
    printer.feed(3)

    print("complete")
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
    queue='texts',
    no_ack=True)
```

and this is the rest of the .py if interesting

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse
import pika, os, sys
from Adafruit_Thermal import *

printer = Adafruit_Thermal("/dev/serial0", 19200, timeout=5)

url_str = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL','amqp://xxxxx')
url = urlparse(url_str)
params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=url.hostname, virtual_host=url.path[1:],
    credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(url.username, url.password))

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='texts')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):

    printer.inverseOn()
    printer.println(' ' + '{:<31}'.format("TXT MESSAGE"))
    printer.inverseOff()

    printer.println(body)
    printer.feed(3)

    print("complete")
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
    queue='texts',
    no_ack=True)

try:

    channel.start_consuming()

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    print "Break detected"
    channel.stop_consuming()

connection.close()

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which pika version you're using; but according to [1],  the callback parameter is the 2nd one.  The queue parameter is first. i.e.

`channel.basic_consume("texts", callback, no_ack=True)`

[1] - https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel